# preventDefault not working on submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this simple form that does a post, but when i press submit on the button (has to be outside the form), the page refreshes even if i have set event.preventDefault() on the submit event. I want to just stay on the page and clear the input fields instead.
I thought maybe the DOMContentLoaded event was the problem but it dont work nomatter if put the code inside DOMContentLoaded listener.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const confirm_btn = document.querySelector("#confirm");
  confirm_btn.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // event.stopPropagation();
    const email = document.querySelector("#email");
    const first_name = document.querySelector("#first_name");

    // Example: Accessing values
    console.log("Email:", email.value);
    console.log("First Name:", first_name.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Single item</title>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- imported header header.html -->
    <header id="header"></header>
    <main>
        <section class="step">
          <form id="address_form" method="post">
            <fieldset>
              <div class="input">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
              </div>
              <div class="input">
                <label for="first_name">First name</label>
                <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" required />
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </section>

        <div class="button">
          <button type="submit" id="confirm" form="address_form">Confirm address</button>

    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The submit event goes on the form, not the button.  Also your submit button is outside the Form element, so doesn't make sense, change to a normal button and manually call the submit on the form if you wish the button to be outside the form.

Comment: `document.getElementById('address_form').addEventListener("submit", (event) => { `

Comment: `has to be outside the form`,  out of curiosity why is that the case?  The reason I ask is that you loose some features of the Form, like default Enter on submit, and say on mobile the keyboard having the default submit on keyboard entry.   Looking at the HTML supplied you should be able to do  `Form->Section->Button` instead of `Section->Form  Button`

Comment: @Keith it is purely because of design reasons it has to be outside the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? 
I tried handling the form tag own submit event

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const address_form = document.querySelector("#address_form"); // >> Change Here!!
    address_form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      // event.stopPropagation();
      const email = document.querySelector("#email");
      const first_name = document.querySelector("#first_name");

      // Example: Accessing values
      console.log("Email:", email.value);
      console.log("First Name:", first_name.value);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the refresh just add a **onsubmit** event condition to your form like this...

```
<form id="address_form" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
```

To also set the form fields to default values, extend it to this...

```
<form id="address_form" method="post" onsubmit="this.reset(); return false;">
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to just clear your form fields, you'll have to change type="submit" to type="button"